# JAVA Finding duplicate values in TreeMap and getting key of same elements

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, treemap

I tried to search forum for answers but I couldn't find solution to my problem. I have  TreeMap which represents polygon . My first task is to return keys of elements with certain value and second task is to return all duplicate vertices. Here is my code and methods I tried to implement:

```
private SortedMap<String, Vertex2D> vertices = new TreeMap<String, Vertex2D>();

//adds vertex to map
public void addVertex(String label, Vertex2D vert){
    if(label == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("label");
    }
    if(vert == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("vert");
    }
    vertices.put(label, vert);
}
```

// these methods aren't working properly

```
public Collection<String> getLabels(Vertex2D vert){
    SortedSet<String> labels = new TreeSet<String>();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Vertex2D> entry : vertices.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue() == vert) {
            labels.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return labels;
}


public Collection<Vertex2D> duplicateVertices(){
    List<Vertex2D> list = new ArrayList<Vertex2D>(vertices.values());
    List<Vertex2D> duplicated = new ArrayList<Vertex2D>();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < list.size() - 1; j++){
                if(!duplicated.contains(list.get(j)) && list.get(j) == list.get(i)){
                    duplicated.add(list.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
    return duplicated;
}
```

I appreciate every help!

Comment: Could you tell us what isn't working exactly, what do you expect and what do you get? It would be nice to know also what you put as "label" when you call "addVertex": are they unique values or not? Also, when you write "if(entry.getValue() == vert)" do you really mean "==", not ".equals()" ? This first is object reference comparison, the second is object equality.

Comment: Beside the problem you're having, your implementation is not efficient. You should not loop twice (squared) on all vertice to find duplicates. It's o(n²) complexity while you could have o(n). But it's another problem

Comment: Yep I realised my description wasn't right. Equals() was the problem, I am not good programmer :D (btw I don't know how to make method duplicateVertices more efficient. I appreciate any idea)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a second TreeMap or HashMap

```
HashMap<Vertex2D, ArrayList<String>>
```

You then iterate over the first TreeMap in your example above and for each element check whether there already is an entry for it and if yes, just add the key to this entries list of strings.

In the end you iterate over this map and check for each entry whether the list has more than one entry, if that is the case you have a duplicate (and do whatever you want to do with it).

There might be other ways with a better performance, but this way will work.

Had a [similar topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325368/counting-unique-occurences-of-string-in-document/27325669#27325669).

Comment: I finally found out why my code wasn't working. Problem was that I was using == on equation in both methods. I should have used equals() which i implemented in Vertex2D class. Stupid me :D

Comment: Oh, okay, in that case use your version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just answering to the efficiency issue, since you've already solved your main problem:

You can find duplicates more quickly using a HashSet. You must know that the method "contains" performs much faster on HashSet than on ArrayList:

```
public Collection<Vertex2D> duplicateVertices() {
    Set<Vertex2D> singleSet = new HashSet<Vertex2D>();
    List<Vertex2D> duplicated = new ArrayList<Vertex2D>();

    for (Vertex2D vertex : vertices.values()) {
        if (!singleSet.contains(vertex)) {
            singleSet.add(vertex);
        } else {
            duplicated.add(vertex);
        }
    }
    return duplicated;
}
```

Another option would be to use guava's HashMultiset. A "HashMultiset" is quite similar to HashSet, but keeps information on number of occurrences:

```
public Collection<Vertex2D> duplicateVertices() {
    HashMultiset<Vertex2D> multiset = HashMultiset.create(vertices.values());
    List<Vertex2D> duplicated = new ArrayList<Vertex2D>();

    for (Multiset.Entry<Vertex2D> entry : multiset.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getCount() > 1) {
            duplicated.add(entry.getElement());
        }
    }
    return duplicated;
}
```